# Remove read-only attribute from folder after Windows reinstall

Tags: windows, read-only

I reinstalled a fresh copy of Windows 8.1 on my laptop after formatting drive `C`. Then I tried to access my Photos folder on drive `D` and got the error

> Access is denied

It turned my folder into a Read Only folder. All other folders on the drive work normally.

I tried using Command Prompt to remove the Read Only attribute but the error message still appears. I tried doing it the simple way (right-click and so on) but the option to change the folder properties from read-only doesn't even appear.

How do I access the folder on my D drive?

Comment: Read-only folders can still be accessed but not modified. Is that the case? Are you able to at least get a directory listing with ``dir /b Photos``?

Comment: Hi Timmy! nope, it doesn't work. It says: file not found. I cannot access the folder in any way

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**The problem isn't that the folder is Read Only.**
Rather, because your folder was created on a different installation of Windows you no longer have NTFS security permissions to access (read) the folder.

Correct this by following these steps to ***take ownership*** and then ***grant yourself full access*** to the folder.

1. Right-click the folder > **Properties**
2. *Security* tab > **Advanced**
3. Click **Change** to the right of *Owner*
4. Enter `Users` into box and click **OK**
5. Enable the checkbox **Replace owner on subcontainers and objects** then click **Apply**
6. If prompted that *You do not have permissions to read...* click **Yes**
7. Completely close out of the *Advanced Security Settings* dialog
8. Right-click the folder > **Properties**
9. *Security* tab > **Edit...**
10. **Add...**
11. Enter `Users` into box and click **OK**
12. Enable the **Full Control** checkbox then click **OK**

Comment: In step 5.) apart from the mentioned checkbox I also had to tick the checkbox at the bottom of the 'Permissions' tab in 'Advanced Security Settings' in order to be able to recursively change the Read-only permission later. 

The box says: "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permissions entries from this object".

Comment: Here I can only see "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permissions entries from this object", where is the "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects"?

Answer (score 4):

Do this in CMD as admin

for the folder

```
attrib -r c:\my-folder
```

and the files

```
attrib -r c:\my-folder\*.*
```

It did the job. I was having issue with PhpStorm. It wasn't able to save the project files because of the read-only status. After doing this in CMD as admin, all is well.

I posted this in Microsoft forum as well - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/in-windows-8-x64-can-not-remove-read-only/81ed233f-9149-4881-bb15-cf0e1ca150e3

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to some permission issue with the user profile after you re-installed the OS

Try to change the permission at Advanced Security Properties. Try these steps and check your outcome.

Right the Folder > Properties > Security tab > select "Authenticated Users" > click on Advanced > click on "Change Permissions" > 'Add' the user in topic > Add the User and click on "Full Control" check box >  click OK.

This will help you to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Easily done with PowerShell for all sub-files and folders:

```
ls -r c:\folder | % { attrib -r $_.FullName }
```

Where aliases:

> ls > Get-ChildItem
>
> % > ForEach-Object