# How to turn off folder write protection? It turns on automatically after disabling

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, c#, write-protect

I have a huge problem! Last week, i performed the newest Windows 10 update. Since then, on each folder im creating or each folder already created, the checkbox on the folder properties "Write protected" is always enabled. When I'm unchecking it and im applying the new settings, the write protection turns automatically back.
I asked google, tried a tool to unlock folder and file protection, tried this link:  [Remove read-only attribute from folder after Windows reinstall](https://superuser.com/questions/846143/remove-read-only-attribute-from-folder-after-windows-reinstall), but nothing helped!

I run chkdsk with admin permission, I checked if my filesystem is NTFS, yes it is, no problems on my hard disk found. I tried the same on other devices, two laptops, but the same problem. Now I'm really helpless, so I thought asking here could help me. I also checked the permissions, i have full access, write and read access.

Why do I need the box unchecked? Im writing a file sync programm in c# and now I'm getting always an: Unauthorized Access Exception, because of the write protection. One week ago i didn't have the problem. After the update, the trouble started. Could someone help me?
Thx!

Comment: Folders do not have write protected status, and that checkbox doesn't really do anything. This has been since many windows versions. If you have a problem with write protection, then there's probably another cause.

Answer (score 1):

Hahaha, after 5 days of searching and finally asking help, I found the problem!! It's not Window's fault, i did a bad mistake in my code! The error was the path I'm handling over to my job execution method! 
I thought the problem is the write protection! My fault, haha! This question can be closed! xD

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts, even delete the question, but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.